# How to create a unique key for a map

Tags: go, hashmap, key

I'm creating a structure where a developer can store a reference to *something* and retrieve it when needed using a reference key, but not delete the reference.

How to create a unique key for a `map` that is generated at the point of insertion?

So far I'm using a not exported pointer to an empty `*struct{}` , but wondering if there there is a better way.

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type referenceKey **struct{}

type reference[K referenceKey, R any] struct {
    s map[K]R
}

func (ref *reference[K, R]) Set(reference R) *K {
    if ref.s == nil {
        ref.s = make(map[K]R)
    }

    key := new(struct{})
    refKey := K(&key)
    ref.s[refKey] = reference

    return &refKey
}

func (ref *reference[K, R]) Get(key *K) R {
    return ref.s[*key]
}

func main() {
    ref := &reference[referenceKey, int]{}
    key1 := ref.Set(77)
    key2 := ref.Set(15345351)
    fmt.Println(ref.Get(key2))
    fmt.Println(ref.Get(key1))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/SF6S5BNlP7N

EDIT:

With `int` I have to keep a reference to it and increment it. To reduce code I tried to use the pointer to a instance of a empty struct.

Basically I need to create a unique key that can't be created outside internal package nor can `Get` method be called with an invalid key.

I've also fixed the code to now allow anyone to create a new invalid key.

Comment: Why not use simply a counter as the key?

Comment: I don't know if you have to use this concurrently, then you may use a Mutex and you can use atomic int as a counter then. See [example](https://gobyexample.com/atomic-counters).

Comment: @icza: Maybe the op needs to have random keys, but a pointer as a key (an int) not random enough I think. Then maybe the best approach is to use a GUID as a key.

Comment: I'm assuming you have a reason for not using a plain `int` or a typed one. Seems highly relevant to the question, so please do include it.

Comment: Keeping a counter is no more hassle than creating your reference keys. And you solution can also be called with an invalid key, anyone can create a value of type `ReferenceKey` and pass it as the key.

Comment: @icza yeah, I saw that. I think I have fixed it now.

Comment: I see no danger in forging and passing an invalid key. The caller will just get the zero value of the value type. Not worth the effort trying to forbid it.

Comment: @icza That would mean that every use of `Get(key)` would require a validity check. I'm trying to make sure that if you have a key you can retrieve a value no matter what.

Comment: Checking if the key exists takes the same amount of time as getting it: `v, ok := m[key]`. And I was telling you can even omit the check, you can index a map with a key that's not in it, in which case the result is the zero value of the value type.

Comment: @icza What if I have a struct and call a method on it? It will panic and the program will crash if not recovered or checked. https://go.dev/play/p/Ty54U7vGDX1

Comment: @CodeBreaker Yes, if you do senseless things, it will result in senseless app / behavior.  You used a key that was not returned by a `Get()` call, why do you expect it to work? What I'm trying to say is that if someone do sensible things, no need to protect from passing an invalid key.

Comment: @icza That is true. I wanted to reduce the ability to do senseless things by having errors thrown at compile time.

Comment: I agree with icza. A pointer is a memory address, and representable with an `uintptr`, it isn't much different than using a counter. Moreover if you constrain `K` to an exact type (`referenceKey`) then you don't need the type parameter anymore

Comment: Is it still not stated that the keys should be random for some security reason?

Comment: @Fenistil They don't have to be radnom, just unique.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments I would make it with a counter and protect the store with a mutex for concurrent use:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type reference[T any] struct {
    mutex   sync.RWMutex
    store   map[uint64]T
    counter uint64
}

func (r *reference[T]) Set(item T) uint64 {
    r.mutex.Lock()
    defer r.mutex.Unlock()
    if r.store == nil {
        r.store = make(map[uint64]T)
    }
    r.counter++
    r.store[r.counter] = item
    return r.counter
}

func (r *reference[T]) Get(key uint64) T {
    r.mutex.RLock()
    defer r.mutex.RUnlock()
    return r.store[key]
}

func main() {
    ref := reference[int]{}
    key1 := ref.Set(77)
    key2 := ref.Set(15345351)
    fmt.Println(ref.Get(key2))
    fmt.Println(ref.Get(key1))
}
```

But if in the future you need to be secure, and the keys should be random, then change the map's key to string, remove the counter and use `uuid.NewString()` for the new key value.